# Why aren't these integer number reaching the cap?

Tags: c#, math

I wanted to try creating a console app that could give me the results of evaluating the Collatz conjecture with several different numbers, but when the program runs up to 113,000 the numbers stop calculating.
In order to do so, I used a (double,int) for calculations.
Here is my reasoning:
if an odd double is divided by 2, you will get a decimal: 2.3,2.4,2.5, and so on; however, if an odd integer is divided by 2 you will get another integer. Using this knowledge, if a number is odd, then the decimal version of the number will not be equal to the integer version.

However, after doing a few tests, I found that the numbers stopped at 113,000. When the max for integers and doubles should be higher.
These are the results.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdHpT.png

The following code bellow checks if a number is even or odd. If the number is even, the number is divided by two, and if the number is odd, the number is multiplied by three and added by 1.
There are no errors listed in the debug screen. My expected result is for the list of numbers to continue up to the int maximum.

```
static (double,int) Checker(double n1, int n2)
    {
        double newn1 = n1;
        int newn2 = n2;
       if(n1/2==n2/2)
        {
            newn1 = n1 / 2;
            newn2 = n2 / 2;

        }
       else 
        {
            newn1 = (n1 * 3) + 1;
            newn2 = (n2 * 3) + 1;
        }
        return (newn1,newn2);
    }
```

The part of code below ensures that each number is calculated using the Collatz conjecture until a result of 1 is released or j = (1,1)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int v = 2;
        int timer = 1;
        int savedv = 1;
        bool run = true;
        bool reached = false;
       
        (double, int) j;
        j.Item2 = -5;
        j.Item1 = 0;
        while (1 == 1)
        {
          
            while (1==1)
            {
                while (reached == false)
                {
                   if (timer == 1)
                    { savedv = v;
                        
                    } 
                    j = Checker(v, v);


                  
                    v = j.Item2;
                    
                    timer += 1; 
                    
                    if (j == (1, 1))
                    {
                        
                        v = savedv;
                       
                        reached = true;
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                if (reached == true)
                {
                        
                 Console.WriteLine("The number" + " " + v + " " + "follows the sequence, and 1 was reached on a timer of" + " "+ timer +"\n" + "Total steps:"+" " + (timer-1));
                    v += 1; 
                    timer = 1;
                    reached = false; 
                    
                }
             
               
               
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to deal with `Int32.MAX_VALUE` & floating point accuracy. Personally I would use `ulong` and shift to divide by 2, at least up to `Uint64.MAX_VALUE`. The problem is that any `n2 *3 +1` could exceed the maximum.

Comment: You're getting an overflow (first should be when v is 113383).  Instead of `newn2 = (n2 * 3) + 1;` try writing: `newn2 = checked(checked(n2 * 3) + 1);` and you'll see the overflow occur as an exception.

Comment: What do you expect `n2/2` to be if `n2` is 1? 2? 3? 4? 5?

Comment: Some code review. Use double literals like `-5.0` rather than `-5` when you are working with doubles. Don't use `while (1==1)`, just use `while(true)`; it's clearer and less error-prone. Consider `var j = (-5.0, 0);` instead of your code. If you are going to explicitly declare your tuples, name the parts. You have `if (j == (1, 1))`. Never test doubles for equality like that. Always assume some inexactness in doubles. Having two very similarly named variables be of diifferent types (`double n1, int n2`) is extremely confusing to the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem you're hitting is that `Collatz(113383)` has an intermediate value that surpasses `Int32.MaxVaue`.

Here's a simpler & faster implementation to demonstrate that point;

```cs
private static void Collatz()
{
    for (ulong i = 1; ; i++)
    {
        var j = i;
        var steps = 0;
        while (j != 1)
        {
            steps++;
            if ((j & 1) == 0)
                j = j >> 1;
            else
            {
                j = (j << 1) + j + 1; // *3 via shifting * addition
                if (j >= Int32.MaxValue)
                    break;
            }
        }

        if ((i%10000) == 0 || j != 1)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} hit {j} after {steps} steps");
        if (j != 1)
            break;
    }
}
```

Outputs;

```
10000 hit 1 after 29 steps
20000 hit 1 after 30 steps
30000 hit 1 after 178 steps
40000 hit 1 after 31 steps
50000 hit 1 after 127 steps
60000 hit 1 after 179 steps
70000 hit 1 after 81 steps
80000 hit 1 after 32 steps
90000 hit 1 after 164 steps
100000 hit 1 after 128 steps
110000 hit 1 after 92 steps
113383 hit 2482111348 after 120 steps
```

Comment: enable [checked mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) and the overflow can be detected quickly

Comment: For some value of "quickly"